# How to check if an element is in a nested list?

Tags: python

How do I check if an element is in a nested list?

I am trying to define a function `nested(x, ys)` that tests if a value `x` appears inside of a nested list of integers `ys`. The result has to have the value `True` of `False`.

Comment: Can we see your effort?

Comment: Is ys a known depth (ie a 2d array) or variable depth (ie a tree)?

Comment: def nested(x,ys):

    if type(ys[0]) == type([]):
            return (nested(x,ys[0]) or  nested(x,ys[1:]))
    else:
        if x == ys[0]:
            return True
        else:
            return False

Comment: This is my effort until now...

Comment: for instance, ys = [[2,1,],3]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loop over the nested lists and test those; the [`any()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) makes this efficient:

```
def nested(x, ys):
    return any(x in nested for nested in ys)
```

This assumes `ys` is nested to one level only.

If recursion is required, you could use:

```
def flatten(lst):
    for elem in lst:
        if isinstance(elem, (list, tuple)):
            for nested in flatten(elem):
                yield nested
        else:
            yield elem

def nested(x, ys):
    return any(x == nested for nested in flatten(ys))
```

I used a simplified test for `list` and `tuple` only to avoid 'flattening' strings.

Comment: I take it there is no recursive nested check in the standard library then?

Comment: There is not; arbitrarily-nested lists are not that uniform to fit a standard function, I'd say.

Comment: Dank je wel, Martij Pieters!

Answer (score 2):

This will work for any level of depth:

```
import collections

def nested(x, ys):
    if x in ys: return True        

    # only keep iterables
    nests = [y for y in ys if isinstance(y, collections.Iterable)]

    # call nested() on each iterable
    return any(nested(x, nest) for nest in nests)

# returns True, will go into multiple nests to find 5
print nested(5, [[1,2],[3,4],[1,2,[3,5]]])
```

Comment: Thanks bcorso. But this is too advanced for me. It works, of course. Thanks.

Comment: How can I use the function nested as a recursion in order to solve the problem?

Comment: This does use recursion. any(nested(x, nest) for nest in nests) recursively calls nested on any iterable element.