# How to modify a list (2D Array) using user input? (Python)

Tags: python, list, input

I am trying to make a basic tic-tac-toe game, so I need the user to input which part of the grid they would like to change into an "X" or "O" (required to use lists). The grid can be accessed using the syntax board[row][column].

```
board = [["1", "2", "3"],
    ["4", "X", "6"],
    ["7", "8", "9"]]

def EnterMove(board):
    player_move = input("Using board[row][column] syntax, make your move: ")
    if player_move in board:      # program doesn't recognize the input here
            board[player_move] = "O"
```

Comment: `board` is nested list so this `if player_move in board` will never work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if an element is in a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295134/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-in-a-nested-list)

Comment: is there any way to "un-nest" it so that it could work?

Comment: See the 2nd comment try that method

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is the best practice, but

```
for row in board:
        if player_move in row:      
                row[row.index(player_move)] = "O"
```